# Find files in a folder using Java

Tags: java, file, search, for-loop, directory

What I need to do if Search a folder say `C:\example`

I then need to go through each file and check to see if it matches a few start characters so if files start

```
temp****.txt
tempONE.txt
tempTWO.txt
```

So if the file starts with temp and has an extension .txt I would like to then put that file name into a `File file = new File("C:/example/temp***.txt);` so I can then read in the file, the loop then needs to move onto the next file to check to see if it meets as above.

Answer (score 81):

What you want is [`File.listFiles(FileNameFilter filter)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)).

That will give you a list of the files in the directory you want that match a certain filter.

The code will look similar to:

```
// your directory
File f = new File("C:\\example");
File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.startsWith("temp") && name.endsWith("txt");
    }
});
```

Comment: BTW Java can handle slash (`/`) just fine under Windows. So there's no need for backslash (and escaping it).

Comment: If you're under Java 7, you could/should use java.nio.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(String dir1, String dir2, ...) to concatenate directories/files in a truly "multiplatform way"

Comment: @beder It's `java.nio.file.FileSystems`

Answer (score 37):

You can use a [FilenameFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html), like so:

```
File dir = new File(directory);

File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
{
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
  {
     return name.startsWith("temp") && name.endsWith(".txt");
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for having slightly more pleasing variable names than the nearly identical code posted 2 minutes before yours.

Comment: @Null Set, that answer was written while I was writing mine, so it's not like I copied what Justin wrote and re-named the variables... :) Thanks for the up-vote, though.

Comment: `+1` For thinking the exact same way I did.

Comment: @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson Right back at you!

Comment: +1 because your variables are named nicers and because your endwith has the extension dot

Answer (score 31):

I know, this is an old question. But just for the sake of completeness, the lambda version.

```
File dir = new File(directory);
File[] files = dir.listFiles((dir1, name) -> name.startsWith("temp") && name.endsWith(".txt"));
```

Comment: This is the sexier solution

Comment: Got me only the first file, the size of the array files is 1

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at `java.io.File.list()`  and  `FilenameFilter`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider Apache Commons IO, it has a class called [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) that has a [`listFiles`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)) method that might be very useful in your case.

Answer (score 5):

As @Clarke said, you can use `java.io.FilenameFilter` to filter the file by specific condition.

As a complementary, I'd like to show how to use `java.io.FilenameFilter` to search file in current directory and its subdirectory.

The common methods getTargetFiles and printFiles are used to search files and print them.

```
public class SearchFiles {

    //It's used in dfs
    private Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    private File root;

    public SearchFiles(File root){
        this.root = root;
    }

    /**
     * List eligible files on current path
     * @param directory
     *      The directory to be searched
     * @return
     *      Eligible files
     */
    private String[] getTargetFiles(File directory){
        if(directory == null){
            return null;
        }

        String[] files = directory.list(new FilenameFilter(){

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return name.startsWith("Temp") && name.endsWith(".txt");
            }

        });

        return files;
    }

    /**
     * Print all eligible files
     */
    private void printFiles(String[] targets){
        for(String target: targets){
            System.out.println(target);
        }
    }
}
```

I will demo how to use **recursive**, **bfs** and **dfs** to get the job done.

**Recursive**:

```
    /**
 * How many files in the parent directory and its subdirectory <br>
 * depends on how many files in each subdirectory and their subdirectory
 */
private void recursive(File path){

    printFiles(getTargetFiles(path));
    for(File file: path.listFiles()){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            recursive(file);
        }
    }
    if(path.isDirectory()){
        printFiles(getTargetFiles(path));
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    SearchFiles searcher = new SearchFiles(new File("C:\\example"));
    searcher.recursive(searcher.root);
}
```

**Breadth First Search**:

```
/**
 * Search the node's neighbors firstly before moving to the next level neighbors
 */
private void bfs(){
    if(root == null){
        return;
    }

    Queue<File> queue = new LinkedList<File>();
    queue.add(root);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        File node = queue.remove();
        printFiles(getTargetFiles(node));
        File[] childs = node.listFiles(new FileFilter(){

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(pathname.isDirectory())
                    return true;

                return false;
            }

        });

        if(childs != null){
            for(File child: childs){
                queue.add(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    SearchFiles searcher = new SearchFiles(new File("C:\\example"));
    searcher.bfs();
}
```

**Depth First Search**:

```
 /**
 * Search as far as possible along each branch before backtracking
 */
private void dfs(){

    if(root == null){
        return;
    }

    Stack<File> stack = new Stack<File>();
    stack.push(root);
    map.put(root.getAbsolutePath(), true);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        File node = stack.peek();
        File child = getUnvisitedChild(node);

        if(child != null){
            stack.push(child);
            printFiles(getTargetFiles(child));
            map.put(child.getAbsolutePath(), true);
        }else{
            stack.pop();
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Get unvisited node of the node
 * 
 */
private File getUnvisitedChild(File node){

    File[] childs = node.listFiles(new FileFilter(){

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pathname.isDirectory())
                return true;

            return false;
        }

    });

    if(childs == null){
        return null;
    }

    for(File child: childs){

        if(map.containsKey(child.getAbsolutePath()) == false){
            map.put(child.getAbsolutePath(), false);
        }

        if(map.get(child.getAbsolutePath()) == false){
            return child; 
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    SearchFiles searcher = new SearchFiles(new File("C:\\example"));
    searcher.dfs();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Appache commons IO various

`FilenameUtils.wildcardMatch`

See Apache javadoc [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#wildcardMatch(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). It matches the wildcard with the filename. So you can use this method for your comparisons.

Comment: So concise answers are prone to be flagged as low quality.

Comment: My reputation does not allow me to add comment. The only way I could contribute is to add another answer. I edited my original post to add more details.

Answer (score 4):

For list out Json files from your given directory.

```
import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FilenameFilter;

    public class ListOutFilesInDir {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            File[] fileList = getFileList("directory path");

            for(File file : fileList) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }

        private static File[] getFileList(String dirPath) {
            File dir = new File(dirPath);   

            File[] fileList = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.endsWith(".json");
                }
            });
            return fileList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

From Java 8 you can use [Files.find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)

```java
Path dir = Paths.get("path/to/search");
String prefix = "prefix";

Files.find(dir, 3, (path, attributes) -> path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(prefix))
                .forEach(path -> log.info("Path = " + path.toString()));
```

Comment: Any way to skip specific folders by path, so that it won't enter them?

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361398/317981), Apache IO Utils might save you some time.  Consider the following example that will recursively search for a file of a given name:

```
    File file = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("the/desired/root/path"), 
                new NameFileFilter("filename.ext"), 
                FileFilterUtils.trueFileFilter()
            ).iterator().next();
```

See:

- [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter))
- org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.FileFilterUtils
- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter.html

Comment: Any way to go over the files as a stream, and skip specific folders by path, so that it won't enter them?

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 1.8, you can use Files.list to get a stream:

```
Path findFile(Path targetDir, String fileName) throws IOException {
    return Files.list(targetDir).filter( (p) -> {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(p)) {
            return p.getFileName().toString().equals(fileName);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You give the name of your file, the path of the directory to search, and let it make the job.

```
private static String getPath(String drl, String whereIAm) {
    File dir = new File(whereIAm); //StaticMethods.currentPath() + "\\src\\main\\resources\\" + 
    for(File e : dir.listFiles()) {
        if(e.isFile() && e.getName().equals(drl)) {return e.getPath();}
        if(e.isDirectory()) {
            String idiot = getPath(drl, e.getPath());
            if(idiot != null) {return idiot;}
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Matcher.[find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) and Files.[walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) methods could be an option to search files in more flexible way
- String.[format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) combines regular expressions to create search restrictions
- Files.[isRegularFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isRegularFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) checks if a path is't directory, symbolic link, etc.

**Usage:**

```java
//Searches file names (start with "temp" and extension ".txt")
//in the current directory and subdirectories recursively
Path initialPath = Paths.get(".");
PathUtils.searchRegularFilesStartsWith(initialPath, "temp", ".txt").
                                       stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Source:**

```java
public final class PathUtils {

    private static final String startsWithRegex = "(?<![_ \\-\\p{L}\\d\\[\\]\\(\\) ])";
    private static final String endsWithRegex = "(?=[\\.\\n])";
    private static final String containsRegex = "%s(?:[^\\/\\\\]*(?=((?i)%s(?!.))))";

    public static List<Path> searchRegularFilesStartsWith(final Path initialPath, 
                             final String fileName, final String fileExt) throws IOException {
        return searchRegularFiles(initialPath, startsWithRegex + fileName, fileExt);
    }

    public static List<Path> searchRegularFilesEndsWith(final Path initialPath, 
                             final String fileName, final String fileExt) throws IOException {
        return searchRegularFiles(initialPath, fileName + endsWithRegex, fileExt);
    }

    public static List<Path> searchRegularFilesAll(final Path initialPath) throws IOException {
        return searchRegularFiles(initialPath, "", "");
    }

    public static List<Path> searchRegularFiles(final Path initialPath,
                             final String fileName, final String fileExt)
            throws IOException {
        final String regex = String.format(containsRegex, fileName, fileExt);
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(initialPath.toRealPath())) {
            return walk.filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path) &&
                                       pattern.matcher(path.toString()).find())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    private PathUtils() {
    }
}
```

[Try](https://regexr.com/4fs1h) *startsWith* regex for \txt\temp\tempZERO0.txt:

```
(?<![_ \-\p{L}\d\[\]\(\) ])temp(?:[^\/\\]*(?=((?i)\.txt(?!.))))
```

[Try](https://regexr.com/4fs1k) *endsWith* regex for \txt\temp\ZERO0temp.txt:

```
temp(?=[\\.\\n])(?:[^\/\\]*(?=((?i)\.txt(?!.))))
```

[Try](https://regexr.com/4fs1q) *contains* regex for \txt\temp\tempZERO0tempZERO0temp.txt:

```
temp(?:[^\/\\]*(?=((?i)\.txt(?!.))))
```