# Files.newDirectoryStream(path) equivalence in android

Tags: java, android

I am new in android programming. I need to access all file names in a directory, in Java we can use Files.newDirectoryStream(path) in order to do so, but since android doesn't support this what should I use instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4852599/115145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something along the lines of the following:

```
File mydir = new File(path);
File[] mydirlist = mydir.listFiles();
```